# How to increase select box character latency time

Tags: javascript, search, drop-down-menu, filter

I am having a select box with more than 1000 options. While trying to search I am getting right result (starting from multiple characters those I typed ) if I am typing fast. But if I am typing slow it shows me fresh result of options starting with last character I typed.

Basically I want to increase that time when browser takes it as a new query string.

For ex. If I am typing fast "Alb" it showing me results starting from "Alb", but if I am typing slowly then on typing "A" its showing results starting with "A" after that if I type "l" it showing me results starting with "l" instead of results starting with "Al".

I tried different js plugins but those are too slow and affecting other part of my code.

Comment: what do you use for the autocompletion ?

Comment: where do your options come from?